# Aluminium fork dropouts hit floor - need to worry?

Tags: fork, damage, aluminum

I had my bike in a bike stand without wheels, clamped by the seat tube. As I loosened the stand mount lock the bike slipped out of my hand and suddenly rotated forwards as most of the weight was in front of the bike stand mount. I **think** the fork dropouts didn't contact the ground, as I believe I caught the bike before, but I can't be sure, and they're all scraped up as it is, so I can't tell by checking for scratches etc.

The front of the bike was around a meter/3 feet off the ground.

The fork is aluminium. There's no bending, cracks etc on the dropouts, they look just as they did before, wheel went in just fine too. Anything to worry about?

Here's an image to illustrate (not my bike):

[image]

Here are my actual dropouts. Note that all the scratches, etc are not new, they've been there before

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'd be worried about the stand and how this happened, and whether or not it can be prevented next-time.

Comment: @Criggie The stand's clamp can be rotated to position the bike as desired, it was mostly my oversight not holding the bike properly when I unlocked the rotation, at that point the weight at the front of the bike pulled it down.

Comment: What's the little black/white lego block?   Is it a second speed sensor or part of a dyno-hub ?   Wire gauge looks too-thin for a power cable for a front wheel ebike and there's only two.  Unrelated, just wondering.

Comment: @Criggie That looks like the power connector for a Shimano dynohub.

Comment: From what I know about aluminum, it doesn't tend to crack and would rather bend, so if the wheel goes in and is true, there's probably not too much damage done. I see disc brakes, so if these haven't mysteriously started rubbing recently, the fork probably didn't get any damage at all. I'm not even sure if that impact was more force than a speedbump or pothole, so probably nothing to worry about....

Comment: I'm sorry I have to ask, but what is anyone even worried about? A fork is designed to withstand far greater forces than that. Or do you also check whether the QR might have got loose and there's cracks inside the dropouts from the axle banging up against them?!

Comment: @arne With the pictures demonstrating that the impact can't have been great, and crucialy must have been in a sensible direction,  I wouldn't worry. But the fork is designed to take those forces *with the wheel in* and *not sideways* so a workshop  drop could be more serious and bend the fork.  It could also chew up the dropout.

Comment: @ChrisH I seriously doubt that for all but the most high-performance carbon fibre forks. Especially not for MTB forks.

Comment: @arne with the leverage of a fork leg, if the weight of a bike falling off a stand landed sideways on one unsupported leg, it would warrant further investigation. Just like after a crash, because the lack of bracing from the wheel more than makes up for only having the weight of the bike to worry about. So before the photos demonstrating how it fell, it was worth thinking about. Fitting a wheel into a slightly misaligned fork, whether caused by a bent leg or a damaged dropout, spoils the handling

Comment: @arne Do note that the MTB pictured is NOT OP's bike. And to be honest, I'd be more concerned if it actually was the MTB--those forks are cast magnesium, which is often more brittle than aluminum. I also support Chris' points. There's a big difference between folding over one dropout vs bending the entire fork with the wheel installed.

Comment: I see a lot of these questions via HNQ: "I bumped or banged part of my bike against something, is it still safe to ride?" - is there a reason that bikes are particularly susceptible to severe damage from this kind of thing, or are bike riders just paranoid, or what gives?

Comment: @user253751 That was exactly my point...

Comment: @user253751 While there's definitely some element of paranoia/overprotection involved, it's true that high-end bikes can be fragile. It's just a natural consequence of simultaneously chasing light weight and high performance. Also, for carbon fiber bikes there is a (somewhat justifiable) concern about hidden damage. With metal, it's usually a pretty binary "is it visibly broken" situation, but composite materials have a risk of internal defects and stuff.

Comment: What material is the floor made of? I'd be more worried about damage to the floor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on new photos - your bike looks fine to ride.  There are no cracks visible and no mushrooming.  Additionally there are no flat spots that would be created by striking the floor.

The impact was likely quite low speed, with the rear of the bike still supported by the clamp and workstand, even though it was rotating.  I expect it was more of a surprise, and the front would also have been rotating not just descending.

Had the wheel been on, it would have been heavier and rotate faster, but with less distance to the ground and a rubber tyre to damp the impact.

If your stand were taller, the fork might have missed the ground completely.

If you're concerned about the visible metal, then clean it well and dab on some appropriately-coloured nail polish, or mask off the brake and sensors and chrome parts then hit with some spray paint.   Normally I wouldn't bother but sometimes it feels nice to ride a tidy bike.  Plus replacing the paint helps show future damage.

Answer (score 2):

Would say, and whole admit there is some risk here, if that's the bike in your pic then I wouldn't be too worried.  That fork doesn't have dropouts, looks like it's got a thru axle configuration.

Based on that I would say the impact forces would have gone straight up the fork, even dampened the suspension somewhat.  Probably find any damage would in most likelihood be cosmetic.

But I would not rule out something more structural based on one photo.

Might also be worth considering a rubberised mat for under your workstand to minimise drop damage, and smaller parts bouncing around when you drop them.

Comment: The photo is for illustrative purposes only, it's not my bike. Mine definitely has dropouts and a QR skewer

Comment: Not sure if I should be leaving this answer here as was based on a couple false assumptions.  Still valid for the original pic?